# Do passengers come at bus stops according to the schedule I created?

Tags: cities-in-motion-2

I have created long bus line (I know it's wrong, but only for testing purpose) where one bus drive only two times daily, and before I ran the line, I configured bus schedule according this idea. After some time when I looked at the bus stops, I noticed that people are waiting there even if the next bus will come in next two or more hours, so they started to be unhappy. Am I missing something or in this game people come to bus stop with hope, instead of checking schedule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Passengers will only consider the *travel time* (completely ignoring the *arrival time*) and the *comfort* when choosing their route. There are quite a bunch of "incorrect" decisions made by passengers, this is just one of them.

A few tweaks have been made over the various patches, but this behaviour is still not fixed. However, their happiness value is now a lot more forgiving for this particular issue than it used to be.